# connecting python to sql server using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

How to connect python to SQL Server using **pyodbc** until now  I wrote the below script but the system crash and display error:

I tried to connect the script to the localhost sql server and  i had a successful connection but when I tried on the server on the same network it did crash

## code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect(
                    ENGINE='sql_server.pyodbc',
                    driver='SQL Server',
                    NAME='testDB',
                    SERVER ='WIN-CMUH9TBNL53',
                    DSN='pythonDSN',
                    PORT='1433',
                    UID='test',
                    PWD="test",
                    
                    )
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql_query=pd.read_sql_query('select * from testDB.dbo.t1',conn)
print(sql_query)
print(type(sql_query))
```

## error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
```

Comment: Is it possible that you need the full domain name to the server?

Comment: Since you're specifying a server name and port why are you also specifying a DSN? Have you read through the Microsoft documentation, [Python SQL Driver - pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc)?

Comment: because using the server name and port did not work

Comment: @mapto it did not work also